# How to change title tags on paginated posts?

Tags: pagination, seo, post-duplication

I've created many post with multiple pages with the nextpage-tag. The problem is that these show up as errors in "Google Webmaster Tools" because of duplicate title tags and meta descriptions.

The urls are like this:

```
http://mypage.com/mypost/
http://mypage.com/mypost/2
http://mypage.com/mypost/3
```

all of which have the same title and meta tags.

Is it somehow possible to include the page number to the meta tags?

I'm using the "WP SEO" which surprisingly doesn't have this feature.

Comment: Hi do you have any answer for this problem, I have the same problem with pagination on my website : [enter link description here](http://www.smo4seo.com) and I can't fix it since 1 mounth ! Best Regards

Answer (score 4):

Is "WP SEO" = "WordPress SEO by Yoast"? If so, the plugin has some tags for you:

- `%%page%%` - Replaced with the current page number (i.e. page 2 of 4)
- `%%pagetotal%%` - Replaced with the current page total
- `%%pagenumber%%` - Replaced with the current page number

Just look at the bottom of the page `wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_titles`, you'll see. Just try it.

Comment: Yes, but I can't define **paginated posts** created by the nextpage tag in this plugin. At least I don't know where.

Comment: I just tried to add %%page%% to the Post title template with no effect.

Comment: @Eddie please use comments for discussion of answers. If you have new details on your question you can edit it to add them.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. You meant *one post with pages* while I was thinking about *pagination of many posts* like in a loop. Ignore the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may just add these lines to your header.php under title tag:

```
<?php if ( $paged < 2 ) { } else { echo (' Page '); echo ($paged);} ?>
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [using the `$page` global](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Inside_the_Loop_variables) to filter `wp_title`:

```
<?php
function wpse24661_filter_wp_title( $title, $separator ) {
    // Globalize $page
    global $page;

    // Determine if current post is paginated
    // and if we're on a page other than Page 1
    if ( $page >= 2 ) {
        // Append $separator Page #
        $title .= ' ' . $separator . ' ' . 'Page ' . $page;
    }    
    // Return filtered $title
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse24661_filter_wp_title', 10, 2 );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is not working due to global variable issue, we have to use '$paged' instead of '$page'.
Following is updated solution

```
function wpse24661_filter_wp_title( $title, $separator ) {
    // Globalize $page
    global $paged;

    // Determine if current post is paginated
    // and if we're on a page other than Page 1
    if ( $paged >= 2 ) {
        // Append $separator Page #
        $title .= ' ' . $separator . ' ' . 'Page ' . $paged;
    }    
    // Return filtered $title
    // echo $title;die;
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse24661_filter_wp_title', 101, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your method. But it's not get reflected in page title on blog pagination. Just hook the `wp_title` as mentioned the same in `functions.php` and ensure the same it's not working can you update any other ways to achieve it.