# Customized title tag for each page in pagination?

Tags: php, customization, pagination, title, description

**With the reference of below questions.**
[How to change title tags on paginated posts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24661/how-to-change-title-tags-on-paginated-posts)
 [Paginate tags page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101549/paginate-tags-page)
 [How to change title tags on paginated posts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24661/how-to-change-title-tags-on-paginated-posts) 
[Add Page number to Meta Description in Wordpress SEO by Yoast](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52002/add-page-number-to-meta-description-in-wordpress-seo-by-yoast)

I am using **WP Page Numbers** plugin for pagination But plugin didn't offer different options.

I would like to add different **title tag** for each page in my **pagination pages**. Below are different pages

**Pagination for all Index pages (50 pages and increasing)**
http:// domain.com/page/2/

**Pagination for all Categories(20 pages each in 4 categories and increasing)** 
http:// domain.com/this-is-category-no-1/page/2/

http:// domain.com/this-is-my-cat-no-2/page/3/

Comment: Please clarify how this question is specific to **WordPress**, rather than specific to **WP Page Numbers** Plugin code.

Comment: Thanks @ChipBennett Infact I don't want to use plugin. that is why requesting code

Comment: Plugin recommendations are inherently off-topic for WPSE. All answers involve actual code. Thus, "without a Plugin" is an arbitrary and invalid limitation. Also: you indicate in your question that you're already using a Plugin, and this question seems to be specific to the code generated by that Plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use a query to display results on each page?

If you know the query arguments then you can do stuff based on the output. Let's say `'posts_per_page'` is set to `20`. You can use found_posts to count how many posts there are, and show a title tag based on that info:

```
$num_posts = $my_query->found_posts;

// For index pages
if(is_page('page_title_here') && $num_posts / 20 == 4){
     // Now you're on page 4
}

// For category pages
if(is_category('category_title_here') && $num_posts / 20 == 3){
     // Now you're on page 3
}
```

If you have `'paged'` set to `$paged` and you've defined `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` then you can make if statements based on the page number (nicer than the above code IMO):

```
// For index pages
if(is_page('page_title_here') && $paged == 4){
     // Now you're on page 4
}

// For category pages
if(is_category('category_title_here') && $paged == 3){
     // Now you're on page 3
}
```

I'm actually not sure what you mean by title tags, but you can do anything you like in within the if statements.

**UPDATE**

If you want the code to put the title in the `<title>` tag in the `<head>` section, wrap the code in a function:

```
function title_function(){
    // For index pages
    if(is_page('page_title_here') && $paged == 4){
         return 'Title for page 4 on page_title_here';
    }

    // For category pages
    if(is_category('category_title_here') && $paged == 3){
         return 'Title for page 3 on category_title_here';
    }
}
```

And put

```
<title><?php echo title_function(); ?></title>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I misread the question, instead of `is_page` in the code above, use `is_home()` if your page shows recent posts, or `is_front_page()` if your homepage is a static page:

```
function title_function(){
    // For homepage
    if(is_home() && $paged == 4){
         return 'Title for page 4 on page_title_here';
    }

    // For category pages
    if(is_category('category_title_here') && $paged == 3){
         return 'Title for page 3 on category_title_here';
    }
}
```

Comment: by title tag i mean <title>Title Tag</title>

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks you very much. this has been very difficult for me.

Comment: for the first condition i think instead of is_page, is_home() is better because it is working for me :). Please change it because i have to accept the answer. thanks again

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121630/manually-insert-title-meta-description-for-pagination-pages @joostvanhoof would you please answer this as well please

Comment: I've updated the answer. Note that `is_home()` returns true only if your homepage contains a list of recent posts. If you use a static page as homepage, use `is_front_page()`. I'll have a look at your other question and answer it if possible.